# Pass total number of files to handler before calling handler in Uploadify

Tags: asp.net, uploadify

I want to pass total number of files to handler's `ProcessRequest` method. My `uploadify` code is as below:

```
input.uploadify({
    'successTimeout': successTimeout,
    'swf': "/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
    'uploader': "/uploadify/Upload.ashx",
    'fileObjName': 'file',
    'multi': true,
    'auto': false,
    'formData': { 'autoauth': true},
    'fileSizeLimit': maxSize == 0 ? '0' : maxSize + 'B', //unlimited or size in bytes
    'buttonText': "Upload",
    'queueID': 'customQueue',
    'removeCompleted': false,
    'onDialogOpen': function () {
    hasErrors = false;
});
```

This will get called on initialization and will not pass total number of files because files will be selected after initialization. So how can I pass total number of files to handler?

Comment: Uploadify uses Flash -- you may find it blocked more and more places...

Comment: @JohnHascall I know that

Comment: OK.  (There are good alternatives).